# MongoDB: Creating calculated fields using the switch function (column aliasing)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

#### Note

I am completely new to MongoDB so my terminology might not be fully correct.

### **Context**

I have some data with various dates in MongoDB and I am trying to use a `$switch` function to provide column aliasing to form some new calculated columns ***however*** I am running into some issues (perhaps syntax or wrong implementation) and want to know why and how to resolve.

### Question

Basically I want to create a new calculated date column which takes the value of the a date field if its not null, else it takes the value of another date field if its not null and so on, however it defaults to some message `"blank"` if there is no values in any of those fields.

**Schema**

A single document with the collection follows this rough structure

```
{
  _id:ObjectId("619756f12c115f24df503c26")
  uniqueid:"12345678"
  date1:"2021-11-02 20:04:50.253"
  date2:"2021-11-03 18:10:57.520"
  date3:"2021-11-08 07:08:00.000"
  date4:"2021-11-08 14:40:00.000"
  date5:"2021-11-08 08:34:00.000"
}
```

### Tried

As part of an aggregation pipeline I tried using the `$project` and then returning all the columns along with the new calculated columns however it comes up with an error at this stage saying `stage must be a properly formatted document` leading me to believe I either my syntax is wrong or perhaps using the wrong operators to do this.

If I remove the calculated column code then the preview seems to work (further convincing me its something to do with my calculated column implementation).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
$project:
      {
      "uniqueid": 1,
      "date1": 1,
      "date2": 1,
      "date3": 1,
      "date4":1,
      "date5": 1,
      "cal_date1": {
          $switch: {
            branches: [
                { case: {"$date2": {$ne: null}}, then: "$date2"},
                { case: {"$date3": {$ne: null}}, then: "$date3"},
                { case: {"$date4": {$ne: null}}, then: "$date4"},
                { case: {"$date5": {$ne: null}}, then: "$date5"}
            ],
            default: "blank"
          }
        },
      "cal_date2": {
          $switch: {
            branches: [
                { case: {"$date4": {$ne: null}}, then: "$date4"},
                { case: {"$date5": {$ne: null}}, then: "$date5"}
            ],
            default: "blank"
          }
        },
       "cal_date3": {
          $switch: {
            branches: [
                { case: {"$date5": {$ne: null}}, then: "$date5"}
            ],
            default: "blank"
        }
      }
    }
}
])
```

**Update1: 2021-11-24 T12:15pm UTC**

I have added in a missing curly bracket at the end of each of the case expressions. The error now is `unknown operator: $date2`

Comment: change this `case: {"$date4": {$ne: null}},` to case: `{$ne:["$date4",null]},` in all of aggregate

Comment: Just had a try but didn't work but made some small alterations and think it has worked! 

I will create an answer but if you can add to it/ edit it as to why it works then that would be good!

Comment: I add this as answer and if possible accept my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this `case: {"$date4": {$ne: null}}`, to `case: {$ne:["$date4",null]}`, in all of aggregate

Answer (score 0):

### Description

It seems that the syntax of my statement is what was causing the issue (not sure why). If someone could elaborate that would be good.

### Answer

Here is the code:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
$project:
      {
      "uniqueid": 1,
      "date1": 1,
      "date2": 1,
      "date3": 1,
      "date4":1,
      "date5": 1,
      "cal_date1": {
          $switch: {
            branches: [
                { case: {$ne:["$date2",null]}, then: "$date2"},
                { case: {$ne:["$date3",null]}, then: "$date3"},
                { case: {$ne:["$date4",null]}, then: "$date4"},
                { case: {$ne:["$date5",null]}, then: "$date5"}
            ],
            default: "blank"
          }
        },
      "cal_date2": {
          $switch: {
            branches: [
                { case: {$ne:["$date4",null]}, then: "$date4"},
                { case: {$ne:["$date4",null]}, then: "$date5"}
            ],
            default: "blank"
          }
        },
       "cal_date3": {
          $switch: {
            branches: [
                { case: {$ne:["$date5",null]}, then: "$date5"}
            ],
            default: "blank"
        }
      }
    }
}
])
```

Notice that the `{"$date_value": {$ne: null}}` within each statement has been changed to `{$ne:["$date_value",null]}` possibly due to the `$ne` operator requiring 2 arguments?

Comment: yeah in projection $ne $lt and some thing operation like this need to array