# MongoDB: Creating a calculated field measuring the difference between date fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

### Context

This question uses the same collection/ document schema construct from my other question: [MongoDB: Creating calculated fields using the switch function (column aliasing)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70093942/15011245)

##### Data Schema

Note: `cal_date1` is the calculated value shown in my other post linked above. When performing these steps they are done in a pipeline so that (I hope) the calculated columns can be thought of as part of the general document schema as shown below.

```
{
  _id:ObjectId("619756f12c115f24df503c26"),
  uniqueid:"12345678",
  date1:"2021-11-02 20:04:50.253",
  date2:"2021-11-03 18:10:57.520",
  date3:"2021-11-08 07:08:00.000",
  date4:"2021-11-08 14:40:00.000",
  date5:"2021-11-08 08:34:00.000",
  cal_date1: "2021-11-03 18:10:57.520"
}
```

### Questions

How can I calculate the difference in date values between two particular dates (with some conditional logic behind it).

##### Extension

Is there a way of calculate the working days between two dates where "working" is defined as dates that are inclusive of Mon-Fri (no Sat, Sun)?

### Tried

I have been playing with the `$dateDiff` operator inside a `switch` function as shown below ***however come across the error*** `unknown operator: $cal_date1`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
$project:
      {
      "uniqueid": 1,
      "date1": 1,
      "date2": 1,
      "date3": 1,
      "date4":1,
      "date5": 1,
      "cal_date1": {
          $switch: {
            branches: [
                { case: {$ne:["$date2",null]}, then: "$date2"},
                { case: {$ne:["$date3",null]}, then: "$date3"},
                { case: {$ne:["$date4",null]}, then: "$date4"},
                { case: {$ne:["$date5",null]}, then: "$date5"}
            ],
            default: "blank"
          }
        },
      "cal_date2": {
          $switch: {
            branches: [
                { case: {$ne:["$date4",null]}, then: "$date4"},
                { case: {$ne:["$date4",null]}, then: "$date5"}
            ],
            default: "blank"
          }
        },
       "cal_date3": {
          $switch: {
            branches: [
                { case: {$ne:["$date5",null]}, then: "$date5"}
            ],
            default: "blank"
        }
      }
    }
}
])

--updated code
"cal_days_between_date1_caldate1": {
    $switch:
    {
     branches: [
     {case: { $eq: ["$date1", null]}, then: "blank"},
     {case: { $eq: ["$cal_date1", "blank"]}, then: "blank"} 
     ],
default: {
          $dateDiff: {
            startDate: {
              $dateFromString: {
                dateString: "$date1"
              }
            },
            endDate: {
              $dateFromString: {
                dateString: "$cal_date1"
              }
            },
            unit: "day"
          }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update: 2021-11-24: T3:08pm UTC**

Have altered the `case` expression slightly to try and get a boolean output and now have a new error of `unknown operator: $dateDiff`

**Update: 2021-11-30: T8:36pm UTC**

Have added in the code which contains the referenced fields (top of code chunk) along with the additions of the `$dateFromString` operator. The calculated date code is meant to act as the next step in the pipeline which I output along with the other fields.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to use Date operators on fields that are strings.

You should transforms your strings to dates before with `$dateFromString`. Check this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lpb9-hJ9N3S) and [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/).
Also there was some mistakes in the `$eq` arrays

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$project": {
    "cal_days_between_date1_caldate1": {
      $switch: {
        branches: [
          {
            case: {
              $eq: [
                "$date1",
                null
              ]
            },
            then: "blank"
          },
          {
            case: {
              $eq: [
                "$cal_date1",
                "blank"
              ]
            },
            then: "blank"
          }
        ],
        default: {
          $dateDiff: {
            startDate: {
              $dateFromString: {
                dateString: "$date1"
              }
            },
            endDate: {
              $dateFromString: {
                dateString: "$cal_date1"
              }
            },
            unit: "day"
          }
        },
        
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah just noticed the `$eq` typo in my question. This wasn't present in my actual code only when typing up the question. Also I still get an error with this however the error seems to be `unknown operator: $date1`

Comment: Are you sure every `$date1`and other references to fields are enclosed in between `"`? Also could you upload your code?

Comment: Yes they all have `"` enclosing them. Have added some more code with an update message.

Comment: It seems fine, I would try to do 2 separate `$project` steps to make sure that you calculated  `cal_dateN` fields exist. like this https://mongoplayground.net/p/B0u4_Bsz1cc If you keep geting errors post your mongoDB version.